# Cycles in directed graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory

I am wiring a function to check whether a graph contains a cycle.

It is represented as a list of lists of all indexes of nodes each node is connected to. Nodes are enumerated from 1 (task requirement).

While checking the graph `[[2, 3], [], [4], []]`, the program enters the first listed node correctly, yet in the second iteration, it is assumed that `adjlist[node-1]` is an `int` of value 3 rather than an array (or `int = 2` at very least)

What am I missing?

The code:

```
def is_acyclic(adjlist: List, visited: List, path: List) -> bool:
    '''
    :param adjlist: list representation of a graph; eg: [[2, 3], [], [4], []]
    :param visited: visited nodes
    :param path: visited nodes in current iteration
    :return: the graph does not contain a cycle
    '''

    for node in range(1, len(adjlist)+1):
        if node not in visited:
            visited.append(node)
            path.append(node)

            for child in adjlist[node-1]:
                if child in path:
                        return False
                elif child not in visited:
                    if is_acyclic(adjlist[node-1], visited, path) is False:
                        return False

            path.remove(node)
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the function is being called recursively. This part of your code keeps trimming the graph adjacency list:

```
        elif child not in visited:
            if is_acyclic(adjlist[node-1], visited, path, level=level + 1) is False:
                return False
```

The first time adjacency list is:

```
[[2, 3], [], [4], []]
```

and `adjlist[node-1]` is `[2, 3]`

the second time around adjacency list is:

```
[2, 3]
```

and `adjlist[node-1]` is `3`

since 2 is already in visited, node actually gets incremented to 2. Hence, you see:

```
 adjlist[node-1] == adjlist[2-1] == adjlist[1] == 3
```